# MATLAB: Plot data fit with prediction

Tags: matlab, confidence-interval

I'm trying to plot the strength increase over the connection length. In the example below, random data similar to what I expect is created, for which a fit is made.
The problem is that I would like to identify the prediction level of every length (every x value), not the prediction level of the entire data set. As one can see in the figure, there results is lot less scattered for low x values than the higher.

Can anyone possible give me a hint in how to create this typ of graph (where the prediction lines is growing away from the fit)?

```
%Generate random data
 xVec = 0:0.001:1;
 Distr = makedist('Normal','mu',10,'sigma',1);
 for i=1:length(xVec)
    yVec(i) = sqrt(xVec(i))*random(Distr);
 end

%Create fit and prediction interval
 FitVec = fit(xVec',yVec','poly4');
 pRvecConf = predint(FitVec,xVec,0.95,'observation','off');

%Plot
 plot(FitVec,xVec,yVec) 
 hold on
 plot(xVec,pRvecConf,'m--')
 legend('Data','Fitted curve','Confidence','Location','se')
 xlabel('Length')
 ylabel('Strength')
```

See the following example plot:
[image: See example plot here]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the yVec was generated by weighting the random distribution with sqrt(xVec), you actually changed the variance of the random variable for each x value by xVec (the square of sqrt(xVec)). What you can do is to re-calculate the confidence interval by weighting the original ones with xVec. Here are some codes based on yours,

```
   %Generate random data
 xVec = 0:0.001:1;
 Distr = makedist('Normal','mu',10,'sigma',1);
 for i=1:length(xVec)
    yVec(i) = sqrt(xVec(i))*random(Distr);
 end

%Create fit and confidence interval
 FitVec = fit(xVec',yVec','poly4')
 pRvecConf = predint(FitVec,xVec,0.95,'observation','off');

 %get the fitting values
 fitY=feval(FitVec,xVec);
 %multiply the confidence interval with sqrt(xVec(i)).^2 
 ci=(fitY-pRvecConf(:,1)).*xVec';
 %get the weighted confidence interval
 Conf_new=[fitY-ci,fitY+ci];

 %Plot
 plot(FitVec,xVec,yVec) 
 hold on
 plot(xVec,Conf_new,'m--')
 legend('Data','Fitted curve','Confidence','Location','se')
 xlabel('Length')
 ylabel('Strength')
```

The result should look like this:
[image: Figure of Modified Confidence Interval]